# Finding available timeslots in a day based on existing records in MySQL

Tags: mysql

I have a table that has these fields:

[image]

How would I find all available time slots for that day (based on the day starting at 7am and ending at 10pm) that aren't currently in this table? For example, on one particular day, if all timeslots from 7am till 10pm were taken bar one at 6pm till 7pm, that would be the one result.

The duration of each time slot does not vary - they all last one hour.

I have tried many different things, but I have a feeling I am so far off, it is hardly worth posting what I've tried.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: you want this in pure sql????

Comment: Can tasks be overlapping in time? Or can the next task entry be at earliest 14:00:00, regarding to your example? Do they always start at a full hour?

Comment: @mind-404 No they cannot overlap, and yes they always start at the hour mark i.e. 14:00, 15:00

Comment: Is Chococrocs answer what you need? Otherwise I would give it another try.

Comment: I have a feeling that his answer answers the question! Thank you very much anyhow!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One thing I would think about would be having a "hours table" with all the values you wanna check. Then, with a left join and selecting only null values, you'd get only the values you haven't assigned. I built a SQLfiddle http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/66b441/6 to check it with some dummy values to show how this works:

```
SELECT h.slot
FROM hours h
LEFT JOIN deliveries d
ON ( h.slot = d.start_time AND date_stamp = '2014-04-04' )
WHERE start_time IS NULL
```

Check the data in the SQLfiddle, if you know the slots and they don't overlap, with that you will get for the date the values

```
SLOT
January, 01 1970 07:00:00+0000
January, 01 1970 10:00:00+0000
```

Comment: If I could give you more than an upvote and an accept I would!